# How do I deal with the Mouse error message "Validation failed for 'ArrayRef'"?

Tags: perl, validation

I call the method `account_balance` which is in a `Test.pm` file from a `srstest.pl` file. I use [GnuPG](http://p3rl.org/GnuPG) to sign my request which I send to the registrar. When I run `srstest.pl` I get the following error:

```
Attribute (extra_args) does not pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for 'ArrayRef' with value --no-secmem-warning at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Mouse/Util.pm line 361
Mouse::Util::throw_error('Mouse::Meta::Attribute=HASH(0x24d4970)', 'Attribute (extra_args) does not pass the type constraint beca...', 'data', '--no-secmem-warning', 'depth', -1) called at /usr/local/share/perl5/GnuPG/HashInit.pm line 6
GnuPG::HashInit::hash_init('GnuPG::Options=HASH(0x1dd69a0)', 'armor', 1, 'default_key', 'abc@test.com', 'homedir', '/root/.gnupg', 'extra_args', '--no-secmem-warning') called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Test.pm line 1766
Test::_sign_client('Test=HASH(0x1db1d48)', 'REGISTRAR: 111111\x{a}REGISTRAR EMAIL: abc@test.com\x{a}P...') called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Test.pm line 245
Test::account_balance('Test=HASH(0x1db1d48)', 'com') called at srstest.pl line 11
```

Line 1766 in the `Test.pm` file:

```
$gnupg->options->hash_init( armor   => 1,
    default_key => $registrar_email,
    homedir => $gpg_dir,
    extra_args => '--no-secmem-warning'
);
```

I do not understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Guessing from the error: `extra_args` should be an array reference, so you should pass the value as an anonymous array

```
extra_args => ['--no-secmem-warning']
```

Comment: Actually its working on other system. but tried this one also Getting  ERROR gpg: no default secret key: No secret key
     gpg: [stdin]: clearsign failed: No secret key

Comment: Mohini, [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for this unrelated problem.

Comment: opened a new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848883/how-to-deal-with-gnupg-error-gpg-no-default-secret-key-no-secret-key-gpg-st